# Relational Database (1 table per user for owned game)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I did not know how to make a title out of it but here s the question.

I have a table of users (lets say 8 millions people) and I wish to make a copy of Steam with all the Users owned game.

(figure 1) Would it be better to make a table per user with every owned game by the user?

OR

(figure 2) Would it be better to make the game table own Users who own the game.

[image]

Comment: Making 8 million tables is surely not going to be any good.

Comment: figure 1 because this is classical solution for many-to-many relation between user and game. but you don't need make unique table for user... just one table that keeps user_id and game_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you would need:

> Table users

```
user_id  | user_name

1          Rick
2          Dwayne
3          Mark
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
```

> Table games

```
game_id  | game_name
1          League of Legends
2          Dota
3          Skyrim
```

---

```
 CREATE TABLE `games` (
    `game_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `game_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`)
)
```

> Table owned_games

```
user_id  | game_id

1          1
1          3
3          2
2          1
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `owned_games` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `game_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `FK_owned_games_users` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `FK_owned_games_games` (`game_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_owned_games_games` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`game_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_owned_games_users` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

This is the perfect layout for your situation. The constraints will delete any rows in owned_games mentioning either a deleted user or game.

Comment: Well I didn't see your answer, I was typing mine XD

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with 3 tables?

Users: holds all user information

Games: holds all game information

OwnedGames: 2 columns. UserID and GameID. Holds a mapping of which Users own which Games.

Comment: Yes but the question is more should i generate a table per user for the owned game or not?

-edit ah i got it from the other anwser